# Jquery autocomplete wont give any result

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am new to `codeignitor` and trying to get `jquery autocomplete` from database . There are already many questions asked about this topic but none of those helped me.

Here is my script function from view file

**View**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-
 ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
 </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $( "#vname" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({
        url: "vendor/search",
        data: { term: $("#vname").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
           var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                return obj.tag;
           }); 

           response(resp);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 2
  });
     });
  </script>
   </head>
    .
    .
    .
    .
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor_name" id="vname" />
```

here is controller(vendor) function (search) from which I am trying to get array of suggestion from database

**Controller**

```
public function search()
{

$json = [];

    $this->load->database();
    if(!empty($this->input->get("term"))){
        $this->db->like('name', $this->input->get("term"));
        $query = $this->db->select('id,name as text')
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->get("vendors");
        $json = $query->result();
    }
    echo json_encode($json);        
}
```

the problem is that when I type in input field, nothing happen (no autocomplete appears) but my vendor/search function is working fine while accessing it directly and pass something as parameter. I think `$_GET[term]` is always empty  or something.

I dont have any idea what to do now any suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: Instead if get() may be try post() on controller and on ajax type: "POST",

Comment: I already tried that. didn't worked

Comment: try to remove ``dataType: "json",`` from Ajax Request

Comment: did you get the json in ajax response?

Comment: please add your auto-completed plugin reference link so the user can get which autocomplete you are using and so they suggest you a good solution. @SanaRiaz

Comment: One more please don't do queries in controller use model. Models are meant to be used for database related query.  @SanaRiaz

Comment: @ankitsuthar i have edited my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
url: "vendor/search",
```

to:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('vendor/search'); ?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in **controller**

```
public function search(){
    $json = [];
    $this->load->database();
    if(!empty($this->input->get("term"))){
        $this->db->like('name', $this->input->get("term"));
        $query = $this->db->select('id,name as text')
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->get("vendors");
        $json = $query->result();
    }
    //set page header
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($json));   
}
```

replace script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#vname" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url(); ?>vendor/search?term="+request.term,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
          response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
            return {
              label: value.text,
              value: value.id
            }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      //select event of autocomplete
      console.log("id : ",ui.item.value);
      console.log("text : ",ui.item.label);
      $('#vname').val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    },
    });
});
</script>
```